# Zend Framework 2 - Redirecting from within a Controller Plugin without returning

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Is is possible to redirect the user to a new URL from within a controller plugin, without having to return a response object to the controller?

Specifically I want to redirect the user to the secure version of the current URL. So in ZF2 I have this:

```
$url = 'https://'.$this->getURL();

$response = $this->getController()->redirect()->toUrl( $url );

return $response;
```

However in the Zend Framework 1 I was able to do:

```
$redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');

$url = 'https://'.$this->getURL();

$redirector->gotoUrlAndExit($url);
```

Is it possible to essentially 'redirect then exit' in ZF2?

Comment: I realize you probably have your reasons for doing this in the app, but you might consider handling this at the web server level, and leave the app agnostic about the port/protocol.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are extending Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin then you should be able to redirect like this:

```
$this->getController()->plugin('redirect')->toUrl($url);
return FALSE;
```

If you look at the toUrl method in Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Redirect, it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Redirect to the given URL
 *
 * @param  string $url
 * @return Response
 */
public function toUrl($url)
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
    $response->setStatusCode(302);
    return $response;
}
```

So obviously it *is* returning the response object, but it has also already added the header to it, and from the controller you don't have to explicitly return the response, so from your plugin you shouldn't either. I think it's commonly done, to maintain a fluent interface, but since you know you don't need it for anything else, you don't need to pass it back.

Note: I have not tested this from within a plugin, but I do this from within the controller and it works fine:

```
$this->plugin('redirect')->toUrl($url);
return FALSE;
```

Comment: You're correct; simply calling that does _eventually_ result in the user being redirected. However not until everything else in the controller's action has been performed, including the view being generated and sent. I was hoping to find I way of returning that response sooner.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're getting at. I modified the plugin calls in the  examples above with return FALSE; which still redirects in the case of the one I tested in the controller. I think it should work the same in your plugin.

Comment: If you expect to be doing a lot of this, and find it objectionable to return FALSE, you could extend the Redirect plugin, and make a new method as toUrlAndExit($url); which works just like the native toUrl($url) method, but returns FALSE instead.

Comment: My problem was when I return FALSE (as in your example), it was returning FALSE _to_ the controller, not _from_ the controller. I've solved this by returning NULL from the plugin if they're already using SSL, and the Response object from toUrl() if not. Then in the controller I check the returned value from the plugin and if it's a Response object, return it. Otherwise I just continue. It's not as tidy as ZF1 allowed, but I think this way I'm at least remaining truer to ZF2's model.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your plugin just return the action:

```
return $this->getController()->getAction();
```